# What is the fastest way to generate 1 billion custom unique code using python and mariadb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb, unique-index

This is the code :

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import time 
import random

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='xxx', database='UniqueCode', 
port='3306', host='192.168.xx.xx')

cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

FullChar = 'CFLMNPRTVWXYK123456789' # i just need that char
total = 5000
count = 10
limmit = 0
count = int(count)
entries = []
uq_id = 0
total_all = 0

def inputDatabase(data):
    try:
       maria_insert_query = "INSERT INTO SN_UNIQUE_CODE(unique_code) VALUES (%s)"
       cursor.executemany(maria_insert_query, data)
       mariadb_connection.commit()
       print("Commiting " + str(total) +  " entries..")
    except Exception:
       maria_alter_query = "ALTER TABLE UniqueCode.SN_UNIQUE_CODE AUTO_INCREMENT=0"
       cursor.execute(maria_alter_query)
       print("UniqueCode Increment Altered")
while (0 < 1) :
   for i in range(total):
      unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count)) 
    
      entry = (unique_code)
      entries.append(entry)


   inputDatabase(entries)
   #print(entries)
   entries.clear()
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

**Output:**

```
Id unique_code
1 N5LXK2V7CT
2 7C4W3Y8219
3 XR9M6V31K7
```

The code above runs well, the time it takes to generate it is also fast, the problem I faced was when the unique_code stored in the tuple was to be entered into mariadb, to avoid data redundancy, i added a unique index in the unique_code column.
The more data that is entered, the more checking of the unique code that will be entered, which makes the process of entering data into the database longer.

From that problem, how can I generate 1 billion data to the database in a short time?

*note: the process will slow down when the unique_code that enters the database is > 150 million unique_codes*

Thank's a lot

Comment: "1 billion data to the database" that sonds impossible. You're going to generate 1 billion unique codes and then store them all in a MariaDB db?  I can't imagine how generating the codes will not be dwarfed by the time it takes to write them to the database.  To answer your question though...what constraints do you have on the codes?  I mean, you can generate 1 billion unique codes by starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 to get the next code.  To test for a unique codes against a set of 1 billion existing codes is not something you're ever going to do quickly unless you have a LOT of memory.

Comment: So far the most record I've ever entered into the database is 200 million unique_codes

I put the generated data into a tuple of 5000 unique_codes, then I put the data into the database. So the data that enters the database is not 1 billion directly but gradually according to the number of unique_codes that are accommodated in the tuple

Comment: "The more data that is entered, the more checking of the unique code that will be entered" this shouldn't be true if the column has a unique index (although commit time will be proportional to the number of records being committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The quick way

If you want to insert many records into the database, you can bulk-insert them as you do now.

I would recommend you disable the keys on the table before inserting and skip the check for unique. Else you will have a bad time like @CryptoFool mentioned.

```sql
ALTER TABLE SN_UNIQUE_CODE DISABLE KEYS;

<run code>

ALTER TABLE SN_UNIQUE_CODE ENABLE KEYS;
```

If I were you, then I would try to play around with the maximum you can insert at once. Try changing `max_allowed_packet` [variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_allowed_packet) in MariaDB if necessary.

### The table

It seems like your `unique_code` could be a natural key. Therefore you could remove the auto_incremented variable, it won't bring much performance but it is a start.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried the "quick way" and the resulting speed is still insignificant